# return alert after creat or edit in kendo ui

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to return alert after the creat by kendo from action and also return custom validation for example: "the username Already taken" but the

```
return JavaScript("<script language='javascript'type='text/javascript'>alert('the username is the username Already take');</script>");
```

don't work!

it's my action :

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddNewCountry([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, CountryViewModel c,int countryId)
    {
        if (c != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            countryService.Create(c);
        }

        //return Json(new[] { c }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
         return JavaScript("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Thanks for Feedback!');</script>");
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How you triggered the `AddNewCountry` action, is it called from AJAX or by normal form submit? If you're using the latter, then return the view and show alert from ViewBag, otherwise just provide alert in `success` setting of AJAX call.

Comment: No, you can't do it that way. Basically, you need to add an error to your model state and then handle your data source's error event. It is described [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid).